# How to send Download Link By hiding directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to send my user download link when a user buys the product. I send the download link through mail. So when i send the `download link` i send it through like.. `www.xyz.com/images/2343354.jpg` 
But i don't want let him know the directory structure. Means when a user tries to access the directory aftwards link `/images/2343355` he could download others images that i don't want to give to that user.
Is there any way i can  avoid by giving the user directory link to download ?

my images are inside the `public/images` directory as i have made a laravel application.

Comment: How user can access your '/images/2343355' directory to download images.give secure permission to it

Comment: Define a separate route for download which abstracts the directory structure and then  write some controller logic to take the id and provide respective image

Comment: Is there any way i could solve it using RewriteCond inside .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Provide hash url to the user like www.xyz.com/download?image=XNS2323NIEYEDUJES
You need to store the image name with related hash value in a table.
In the download page get the image request data and retrieve the original image name from db.
And the Make download with PHP download code.

```
<?php
//get original filename with hash name from fb and store in a variable
if($dboriginalfilename!="")){
    $fileName = basename($_GET['file']);
    $path = set ur path;
    $filePath = $path.$fileName;
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){
        // Define headers
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        // Read the file
        readfile($filePath);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
}
```

I think this will work for you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript function like this which will download file and user will not get to know what url is called.

Here is sample solutions which you can try

```
<a href="" id="yourlinkId" onclick="downloadfile('file');">download</a>
    <script>
    function downloadfile(filename){
    var file_path = 'host/path/'+filename+'.ext';
    var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); //or grab it by tagname etc
    a.href = file_path;
    a.download = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = '';//remove path after download
    }
    </script>
```

In this code a normal link will be displayed without any href and download file.Then after on click of it you will pass only filename and file will be downloaded then after that if user hover over link no path will be displayed.

Here file name in on-click('filename) will be dynamic each time and directory path is static in your script.

Try this once.